# Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping, however mapping has no issue

Tags: asp.net, automapper

So I am getting this error missing or unsupported mapping despite no clear problem.

This is my student model class where I want to list students along the class which has an id in student table.

`StudentViewModel` -

```cs
public class StudentViewModel
{
    public int student_id { get; set; }
    public int class_id { get; set; }
    public string student_name { get; set; }
    public string father_name { get; set; }
    public ClassViewModel Class { get; set; }
}
```

`ClassViewModel` -

```cs
public class ClassViewModel
{
    public int class_id { get; set; }
    public string class_name { get; set; }
}
```

It gets the student list but when it comes to service layer in the second last line it gives exception that `ClassViewModel` mapping is incorrect. So when I remove `ClassViewModel` from `StudentViewModel` and it works, but with that it doesn't. I don't know why.

```cs
public List<StudentViewModel> GetStudents()
{
    List<Student> s = sr.GetStudents();
    var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => { cfg.CreateMap<Student, StudentViewModel>(); cfg.IgnoreUnmapped(); });
    IMapper mapper = config.CreateMapper();
    List<StudentViewModel> svm = mapper.Map<List<Student>, List<StudentViewModel>>(s);
    return svm;
}
```

Comment: "_however mapping has no issue_" - are you sure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `Student` class has a property named `Class` of type `Class`, like -

```cs
public class Student
{
    // other properties
    
    public Class Class { get; set; }
}
```

then simply add a mapping from `Class` to `ClassViewModel` -

```cs
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<Student, StudentViewModel>();
    cfg.CreateMap<Class, ClassViewModel>();    // <-- add this one
});
```